# Does the disjoint union of an indexed family of sets need the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory

I have an indexed set $\{O_i:i\in I\}$ (which are orbits of the action of a group on a set), and I would like to define what I know as sum or disjoint union:
$$ \sum_{i\in I} \mathscr P(O_i) = \bigcup_{i\in I} \big(\{i\}\times \mathscr P(O_i)\big) = \{(i,\mathscr P(O_i)): i\in I\} $$
where $\mathscr P(O_i)$ is the powerset of $O_i$.
Is this construction non-empty and well-defined using only Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms, without AC?

Comment: Where do you think that the axiom of choice might be needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You already showed that it is well-defined (by providing the definition*) and for any $i \in I$ we have $(i, \emptyset) \in \sum_{i \in I} \mathcal P(O_i)$, so it is nonempty as well.

You probably have in mind that there may be a sequence of nonempty sets $(A_i \mid i \in I)$ such that $\prod_{i \in I} A_i$ is empty. But this is a totally different story.

*Maybe I missed your point here. If you are worried that it may be a proper class instead of a set - the same proof as in ZFC shows that it is in fact a set. (Alternatively: Note that the collection of $\in$-ranks of all elements in $\sum_{i \in I} \mathcal P(O_i)$ is bounded and then recall that any definable collection with bounded $\in$-ranks is a set.)